# Xcode 7.3- App installation failed

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to compile my app on my device (iPhone 5c),the Xcode occur this:

> App installation failed
>
> An unknown error has occurred.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPLRm.png)

I have 3 certificates,and all of them are free .I tried every certificate,and the results are the same. I checked the device log and got this

> Oct 14 16:50:26 my-iPhone installd[43] : 0x40115000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/RemoteProjector.app" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 208)
>   Oct 14 16:50:26 my-iPhone installd[43] : 0x40115000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing 
>   Oct 14 16:50:26 my-iPhone profiled[124] : (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
>   Oct 14 16:50:26 my-iPhone profiled[124] : (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
>   Oct 14 16:50:27 my-iPhone securityd[94] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
>   Oct 14 16:50:27 my-iPhone securityd[94] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
>   Oct 14 16:50:27 my-iPhone installd[43] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Oct 14 16:50:27 my-iPhone online-auth-agent[200] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
>   Oct 14 16:50:29 my-iPhone installd[43] : MIS: unrecognized status -67049 from codesigning library
>   Oct 14 16:50:29 my-iPhone installd[43] : MIS: Could not copy code signature (error 0xe8008001).
>   Oct 14 16:50:29 my-iPhone installd[43] : 0x40115000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 142: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FoKjim/extracted/RemoteProjector.app/Frameworks/SRPAAS.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)
>   Oct 14 16:50:29 my-iPhone installd[43] : 0x40115000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[208] : 0x40115000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FoKjim/extracted/RemoteProjector.app/Frameworks/SRPAAS.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)" UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620415, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FoKjim/extracted/RemoteProjector.app/Frameworks/SRPAAS.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.), SourceFileLine=142}
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[208] : __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:299: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/RemoteProjector.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.FoKjim/extracted/RemoteProjector.app/Frameworks/SRPAAS.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone SpringBoard[48] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone atc[35] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone UserEventAgent[23] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone BTServer[74] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone apsd[97] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone iaptransportd[29] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone itunesstored[99] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone homed[127] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone passd[125] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone profiled[124] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Oct 14 16:50:30 my-iPhone nsurlsessiond[119] : [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
>           " sweety <(null) *Not found in database*>"
>       )
>   Have you met this issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using free development provisioning profile that you can create with Xcode then this is what you can do:

Steps:

1) Reset the development profile in Xcode Preference

2) Remove your Apple Account from Xcode Prefrences

3) Add Again

4) Create Again

5) Clean & Run

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your way,but it din`t work. I finaly figured out it must have some bugs in my project,because when i creat a new project and complie it with the same development provisioning profile ,it worked. There are two targets(A and B) in my project. B target produce a Framework,and A target quotes the framework. it`s compile issues of B target.